# Can't make any DNS lookups to "external" DNS servers?

Tags: docker, networking, dns, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I'm trying to fix a bug in my Docker stack for the past few weeks now but to no avail.

This is the compose file in question (stripped down to the relevant stuff):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  php:
    ...
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
networks:
  default:
    internal: true
      driver: overlay
```

It deploys just fine until I have to do *anything* that is requires an "external" DNS request.
Eg. in my container I manually run `curl https://www.google.com`.
This results in the following error

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com

This is the content of my `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the container:

```
search finlaydag33k.nl
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Running `docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.DNS}}' container-id` results in the following output:

> [1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1]

My question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?
It can reach services within the same stack by dns name just fine, just not domains that require and external DNS (like `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8`).
Nothing is beeing blocked by my firewall.

Comment: are you able to ping 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 from within the container ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not. Mostly because there is no `ping` command in the container.
I am able to ping using a little busybox container that I temporarily ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a "doh" moment.
Apparently (though I could not find this in the docs), a container is only hooked up to the `default` network, which is an `overlay` network.
This means that one has to explicitly add a `bridge` network (one should already be present on your swarm) to this container (and also explicitly hook it to the `default` network so it can communicate with other containers in the stack).

This was not documented so I assumed it was able to reach the outside already.
After manually adding the `default` and `bridge` networks to the container, everything works as expected.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  php:
    ...
    networks:
      - default
      - bridge
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
networks:
  default:
    internal: true
      driver: overlay
  bridge:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a DNS forwarder to '/etc/resolv.conf' by adding

```
  server=8.8.8.8
  server=1.1.1.1
```

See if curl is now resolving google after you have added this